# PHP - Using WHERE in INSERT ON DUPLICATE UPDATE issue

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've looked everywhere and cannot find an answer

I have a insert on duplicate update, i need to specify where Rest_ID = '$rest_ID', but i am receiving the following error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server 
>       version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE Resturant_ID ='1'' at line 41.

What is the best way to do this, is it using IF instead of WHERE?

This is what i am using at the present moment

```
        if (isset($_POST['Save-dets'])) {
        $rest_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_SESSION['Resturant_ID']);

        $r_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['rest_name']);
        $r_desc = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['Desc']);
        $r_addl1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['address1']);
        $r_addl2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['address2']);
        $r_city = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['city']);
        $r_pcode = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $_POST['pcode']);

        $insert_rest = "INSERT INTO Rest_Details
  ( Resturant_name
  , Resturant_des
  , Res_Address_Line_1
  , Res_Address_Line_2
  , City_name
  , Resturant_Postcode
  ) 
  VALUES
  ( ?
  , ?
  , ?
  , ?
  , ?
  , ?
  ) 
  ON DUPLICATE KEY 
  UPDATE Resturant_name               = VALUES(Resturant_name)
  , Resturant_des        = VALUES(Resturant_des)
  , Res_Address_Line_1              = VALUES(Res_Address_Line_1)
  , Res_Address_Line_2 = VALUES(Res_Address_Line_2)
  , City_name = VALUES(City_name)
  , Resturant_Postcode              = VALUES(Resturant_Postcode)
   WHERE Resturant_ID ='$rest_id'";
```

Comment: you can't use where with duplicate

Comment: @YourCommonSense i just read a manual that says i can, which didn't seem right, thats why i am asking

Comment: It's funny how you're using prepared statements, but you don't use it for `Restaurant_ID` value. The other thing is - what would `WHERE` clause accomplish? If you hit unique constraint, `INSERT` isn't processed, but `UPDATE` is, because the record is known already.

Comment: @N.B. yeah, it was me just testing if it would work, then i would have changed it to a prepared statement. The reason i decided to do this, is because when i press update it seems to make a new record in the database instead of updating. So i thought that by adding a Where statement, this would resolve my issue.

Comment: Do you have any unique constraint besides primary key?

Comment: @N.B. yes i do. restaurant name is unique

Answer (score 1):

> i need to specify where Rest_ID = '$rest_ID',

You don't.

Specifying WHERE clause for the `ON DUPLICATE KEY` query makes absolutely no sense.

You have to provide the primary key variable in the INSERT clause instead.

Besides, you shouldn't use escape string with prepared statement.

Comment: yeah, it was me just testing if it would work, then i would have changed it to a prepared statement. The reason i decided to do this, is because when i press update it seems to make a new record in the database instead of updating. So i thought that by adding a Where statement, this would resolve my issue. sorry its actually restaurant_ID which has been specified

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to create one query to handle `create` and `update`. So i won't make the obvious comment of using an UPDATE statement if you know the ID of the record you want to update.

Essentially you just need to add the `Restaurant_ID` column to your `INSERT` columns. If you dont have an ID such as a create operation, use `NULL` instead.

For example:

```
# Create a new entry in foo
INSERT INTO foo(id, title) VALUES(NULL, "new title") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE title=VALUES(title)

# Update an entry in foo
INSERT INTO foo(id, title) VALUES(10, "new title") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE title=VALUES(title)

# Alternative method
REPLACE INTO foo(id, title) VALUES(10, "new title");
```

> Note: the alternative method will delete the old row and create a new
>   one when a dupe key is detected. It's a useful alternative as you
>   don't have to specify all the columns to update, but you should ensure
>   it wont cause any issues first.